# Android resource linking failed. error: attribute iconGravity not found

Tags: android

I’m trying to add an icon to my app like it described in Chapter 2, “Adding an Icon” of
Android Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide, 5th Edition. But when I’m trying to run my app it fails with error:

> Android resource linking failed
> com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.app-mergeDebugResources-48:/layout/activity_main.xml:43:
> error: attribute iconGravity (aka
> com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz:iconGravity) not found. error: failed
> linking file resources.

In `activiy_main.xml` everything is like in the book.
[image]

The icon added here:
[image]

I guess that something is wrong in my dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
}
```

Could you please help me to solve the problem?

Comment: Seems like resource issue. Have you added the icon resource at right place?

Comment: I think the icon resource is at the right place. I updated the question with a screenshot of the icon resource.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that `Button` has an attribute `android:drawableEnd`.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well i am not aware about tutorial you are following or what you are trying to achieve because dependencies are mentioned for compose and you are trying to create layout in xml but anyways issue is that you are trying to add attribute `iconGravity` on `Button` which doesn't support it . `iconGravity` is supported by `com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton` so if you want to use `iconGravity` , you have to use `MaterialButton`